# Git label decoration in Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I have a file which is in committed to the repository. I am using Eclipse Juno and EGit version 2.3.1... It has a strange symbol that is not described in Preferences->Team->Git->Label Decorations. 
An image is in the link.

[decoration](http://bergoo.se/pontus/symbol.png)

Does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks

Comment: Does it look like in the picture in the Branch Status Decoration section here?: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/1.3#Branch_Status_Decoration

Comment: No it is not that decoration. There is now an image in the decoration link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only label decoration in that image by EGit is in the bottom right part, the "repository" cylinder. The arrow is part of the icon itself and is not provided by EGit.

See the image on the [Dali Plugin of the Eclipse EE package](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) where you can see the same icon in the editor tab of the `persistence.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explains the thing.

Comment: @user1822893: Good to know. If an answer is correct, it should be marked as accepted with the green check mark (and optionally upvoted), see here: http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/accepted-answer